# I have created all substrings from a string , now I want to store all sub strings that start with'aeiou' into an empty list . can you check error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, python-2.7

```
string ='shivraj'
i=0
j=0
a=[]                                      //storing the sub strings into empty list
for i in range(len(string)):               //for loop to create sub strings 
    for j in range(i,len(string)):               
        a.append((string[i:j+1]))
        j=j+1
    i=i+1
s=[]                          //empty list to store sub strings starting with vowel
k=0
l=0
for x in range(0,len(a)):               //loop to run for entire sub string list
    if a[k][l] in 'aeiou':              // [l] to extract first letter of sub string and match it 
       s.append(a[k])                      with 'aeiou' and store it in s=[] if matched.       
       k=k+1                            // to increment for next index values
```

My output comes out to be an empty list (s=[]) after running the enire code , can you please help me getting the error ?

Comment: you are not incrementing the `l` value

Comment: [l] is used to extract the first value of sub string , so I have kept it as l=0 , for every time  the loop runs

Comment: can you add expected output

Comment: the expected output should be list of strings that starts with vowels 'aeiou' , I have tried very to find the error in code but couldnot able to find ,FYI ,firstly  my code gives you a  list of all   sub strings ,then I want to have a separate list where i see only substrings that starts with vowel and that i am not able to do, I mean the error is in the last lines of code

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code is `k` will increment only if condition is True. You just move the `k = k+1` out of if statement it will work.
Change this

```
for x in range(0,len(a)):               
    if a[k][l] in 'aeou':              
       t.append(a[k])                     
        k=k+1
```

This

```
for x in range(0,len(a)):               
    if a[k][l] in 'aeou':              
       t.append(a[k])                     
    k=k+1
```

Simple Solution using list comprehension

```
string ='shivraj'
a = [string[i: j + 1] for i in range(len(string)) for j in range(i, len(string))]                                      
vowels = 'aeiou' 
s = [x for x in a if x.startswith(tuple(vowels))]
```

**Output:**

```
['i', 'iv', 'ivr', 'ivra', 'ivraj', 'a', 'aj']
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer , but I really want to know the error in my code , If you can help me in that , it would  be a learning to me.

Comment: @VarishTripathi I have added the explanation why your code is not working